# Propel having() with criteria

Tags: propel

I add a virtual column, then I filter it using "having". When I need to filter by one value, all works fine, but I also need to filter by "not null". having expects only 3 arguments, including the clause, the value and the binding type, is there any way to pass in a criteria?

```
$Sharings->having("TotalSharing = ?",2, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Or do I have to add a new virtual column who has as value what I need directly?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Gioia

Answer (score 1):

Ok, was actually a lot easier then I thought, I just used:

```
$Sharings->having("TotalSharing > ?",0, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

So I didn't need to use a Criteria object, silly of me not to think about this, just so used to use filterBy...